# Excel date convertion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, jdedwards, vba

Thanks for checking.
I exported a DUMP from JDE(JD Edwards enterprise Resourse Planning Application) to an excel file. i intend importing the excel file to MS SQL Server so that each departments can run a report from my application which i will then export as an excel file.
But the issue i am having is that the date in my imported excel file is not in the same format. some are strings while some are date although they look like a valid date. the same applies to the field containing the total amount for each transaction. So when i try to import to MS SQL all the data that are not in date format are replaced with null.
Please does any have an idea of how i can make all the values in the date column to have the same data type. i have tried using the following suggestions but haven't gotten a result yet.
`=DATEVALUE(10/03/2014)`
`` `10/03/2014 ``

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Even if it is a macro.

Comment: Which JDE version are you getting the data? Is it World or EnterpriseOne?

Comment: EnterpriseOne edition

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem to the above that may help someone.  Excel interpreted dates imported from CSV as text (mm/dd/yy) and some as dates (mm/dd/yyyy), but applied my local settings (dd/mm/yyyy).  The following fixed the mix of text and dates:

```
=IFERROR(
DATE(
MID(B1,FIND("/", B1,FIND("/", B1)+1)+1,LEN(B1)-(FIND("/", B1,FIND("/", B1)+1)))+2000,
LEFT(B1,FIND("/", B1)-1),
MID(B1,FIND("/", B1,FIND("/", B1))+1,FIND("/", B1,FIND("/", B1)+1)-FIND("/", B1)-1)),
DATE(YEAR(B1),DAY(B1),MONTH(B1)))
```

The first "DATE" uses the "/" character in the text to extract the date.

- NOTE: formula assumes yy to be 20yy.

The last "DATE" reverses the "DAY" and "MONTH" of the incorrectly interpreted dates.

The "IFERROR" defaults to the last date when "FIND" does not locate "/" in an Excel date (456789).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your windows / excel regional settings for date format are different than the the JDE dump?

Check the "dates" that are recognized by changing the format to display the month as text to verify that it is actually interpreted correctly.

Comment: is there a way to change the regional setting? i am using west central African timezone in my windows machine. even when i change the date format in excel to UK.(dd/mm/yyyyy) it gives the desired output but the datatype still is not the same, i dictate this when i am importing to sql server. the data types in text are replaced with null.

Comment: What format are the exported JDE dates in?  DD/MM/YYYY?  Can you add an additional column to "calculate" the correct date?  Assuming the problem is caused by a flipped month /date , you could use a formula similar to this:  =if(isnum(a2),date(year(a2),day(a2),month(a2)),date(right(a2,4),mid(a2,4,2),left(a2,2)))

Comment: thanks. but i solved the problem. my date formate was mixed ie from jde. `01/02/2014` `21/02/2014` in my region and language setting i was using USA(mm/dd/yyyy) as against United Kingdom(dd/mm/yyyy) so any date above this is ignord `12/02/2014`. I just changed It exported again and everything worked fine. Thanks all for your contributions.